# Regular Expression is not working properly in laravel validation

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel validation. I want to take input and store data like this. 
`111-111-111`. This is the demo value. There should be 3 number in each part. 
Here is my validation rule

```
'id'  => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/|unique:info',
```

First two part working perfect but in last part I can take more than 3 number. I mean if input is `111-111-11111` it take the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal.
You need to think about regex like a search engine. With your rule, you actually say:

```
Is there a string that has 3 numbers and then a hyphen (-)
                           3 numbers and then a hyphen (-)
                           3 numbers
```

So this is true:

```
123-112-111
```

But also this is true:

```
111-111-111111111
145-156-1155
123-456-87897
```

Because all of them have the 3 numbers and hyphen, 3 numbers and hyphen, 3 numbers and hyphen!

You need to limit your input differently. Maybe with another rule in controller, for example:

```
'id'  => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}/|max:11|unique:info',
```

This was just a basic example, I am sure you can figure out something even better.

Also check this website: https://regexr.com/

---

#### Update

This is actually the best solution for your problem:

```
/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/
```

With `$` at the end of your regex you say:

This is the end of my string, don't accept the input if user writes more than 3 characters after second hyphen.

Comment: it worked fine.thank you so much. But still I am confused why my condition is not working.Because I have set three number for last part. then why more than three number it is accepting. can you please explain me if you can.

Comment: Because it matches your rule...It doesn't limit it...It's like when you search something on the Internet or on your OS. When you type and search for: `controller` that word matches also all the words that have `controller` inside. So UsersController is a match, ItemsController is a match... Same thing with your regex rule. It matches no mather how many numbers you write at the end.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.